# Zipping two collections with possible null values in Javascript (lodash available)

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have two arrays of objects. Each collection object contains similar properties. I'm trying to zip together the two collections based on a specific property. It's possible, however, that a particular object in either array may not necessarily have a object with a matching property value in the other array. In these cases I'd like to have null values. Here's an example of what I'd like to do:

```
var arr1 = [
  { id: '1', text: 'arr1 - one' },
  { id: '2', text: 'arr1 - two' },
  { id: '3', text: 'arr1 - three' }
];

var arr2 = [
  { id: '1', text: 'arr2 - one' },
  { id: '2', text: 'arr2 - two' },
  { id: '4', text: 'arr2 - four' }
];
```

result:

```
{ 
  '1': [
    { id: '1', text: 'arr1 - one' },
    { id: '1', text: 'arr2 - one' }
  ]

  '2': [
    { id: '2', text: 'arr1 - two' },
    { id: '2', text: 'arr2 - two' }
  ],

  '3': [
    { id: '3', text: 'arr1 - three' },
    null
  ],

  '4': [
    null,
    { id: '4', text: 'arr2 - four' }
  ]
```

I do already have a lodash 4 dependency in the project, so answers using that library are welcome.

Comment: Is the ordering of the result important?

Comment: Yes and no. The final place where this is used the keys would need to be sorted. However, if they were random, I could easily enough work around it by using Object.keys(), sorting the result, then using the sorted array to grab the info in the right order.

Comment: Minimum browser/node?

Comment: Browser IE10, using babel in the build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
_.chain(arr1)
    .concat(arr2)
    .map('id')
    .uniq() //get all possible ids without dublicates
    .reduce(function (result, id) {
        result[id] = _.map([arr1, arr2], function (arr) { //find object in each array by id
            return _.find(arr, {id: id}) || null;        //if not found set null
        });
        return result;
    }, {})
    .value();
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function zip(a, b, propName) {
    const result = new Map();
    a.forEach(i=> result.set(i[propName], [i, null]));
    b.forEach(i=> {
       let item = result.get(i[propName]);
       item ? (item[1] = i) : (result.set(i[propName], [null, i]));
    });
    return result;
}

var arr1 = [
  { id: '1', text: 'arr1 - one' },
  { id: '2', text: 'arr1 - two' },
  { id: '3', text: 'arr1 - three' }
];

var arr2 = [
  { id: '1', text: 'arr2 - one' },
  { id: '2', text: 'arr2 - two' },
  { id: '4', text: 'arr2 - four' }
];
console.log(JSON.stringify([...zip(arr1, arr2, 'id')], null, '  '));
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the requirements listed, below should work (using `Ramda`, I believe the functions used should have according one in `lodash/fp`)

```
var arr1 = [
  { id: '3', text: 'arr1 - one' },
  { id: '2', text: 'arr1 - two' },
  { id: '1', text: 'arr1 - three' }
];

var arr2 = [
  { id: '4', text: 'arr2 - one' },
  { id: '2', text: 'arr2 - two' },
  { id: '1', text: 'arr2 - four' }
];

var idList = R.pipe(
  R.concat,
  R.map(R.prop('id')),
  R.uniq,
  R.sortBy(R.identity)
)(arr1, arr2);

var findById = (id) => R.find(R.propEq('id', id));

return R.map(
  (id) => [
    findById(id)(arr1),
    findById(id)(arr2)
  ]
)(idList);
```

Here's the [link](http://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.22.1#?var%20arr1%20%3D%20%5B%0A%20%20%7B%20id%3A%20%273%27%2C%20text%3A%20%27arr1%20-%20one%27%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%20id%3A%20%272%27%2C%20text%3A%20%27arr1%20-%20two%27%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%20id%3A%20%271%27%2C%20text%3A%20%27arr1%20-%20three%27%20%7D%0A%5D%3B%0A%0Avar%20arr2%20%3D%20%5B%0A%20%20%7B%20id%3A%20%274%27%2C%20text%3A%20%27arr2%20-%20one%27%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%20id%3A%20%272%27%2C%20text%3A%20%27arr2%20-%20two%27%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%20id%3A%20%271%27%2C%20text%3A%20%27arr2%20-%20four%27%20%7D%0A%5D%3B%0A%0Avar%20idList%20%3D%20R.pipe%28%0A%20%20R.concat%2C%0A%20%20R.map%28R.prop%28%27id%27%29%29%2C%0A%20%20R.uniq%2C%0A%20%20R.sortBy%28R.identity%29%0A%29%28arr1%2C%20arr2%29%3B%0A%0Avar%20findById%20%3D%20%28id%29%20%3D%3E%20R.find%28R.propEq%28%27id%27%2C%20id%29%29%3B%0AR.map%28%0A%20%20%28id%29%20%3D%3E%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20findById%28id%29%28arr1%29%2C%0A%20%20%20%20findById%28id%29%28arr2%29%0A%20%20%5D%0A%29%28idList%29%3B%0A). It's returning `undefined` instead of `null`, but you can map over it to change it if it matters.

However, depending on what the result would be used, if `null` value is not required at all, there is simpler version with `groupWith`

```
return R.pipe(
  R.concat,
  R.sortBy(R.prop('id')),
  R.groupWith(R.eqProps('id'))
)(arr1, arr2);
```

[link](http://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.22.1#?var%20arr1%20%3D%20%5B%0A%20%20%7B%20id%3A%20%273%27%2C%20text%3A%20%27arr1%20-%20one%27%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%20id%3A%20%272%27%2C%20text%3A%20%27arr1%20-%20two%27%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%20id%3A%20%271%27%2C%20text%3A%20%27arr1%20-%20three%27%20%7D%0A%5D%3B%0A%0Avar%20arr2%20%3D%20%5B%0A%20%20%7B%20id%3A%20%274%27%2C%20text%3A%20%27arr2%20-%20one%27%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%20id%3A%20%272%27%2C%20text%3A%20%27arr2%20-%20two%27%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%20id%3A%20%271%27%2C%20text%3A%20%27arr2%20-%20four%27%20%7D%0A%5D%3B%0A%0Apipe%28%0A%20%20concat%2C%0A%20%20sortBy%28prop%28%27id%27%29%29%2C%0A%20%20groupWith%28eqProps%28%27id%27%29%29%0A%29%28arr1%2C%20arr2%29).

Answer (score 0):

The thing that makes this a bit difficult is the need for null values in each grouping, which match the order in which they were grouped. For example, if you did not need the nulls, this problem would be as simple as:

```
_.groupBy(arr1.concat(arr2), 'id')
```

However, to group and maintain nulls, you need to add a bit of redundancy that `groupBy` does not come pre-baked with. You can write your own group function as such:

```js
function group(...arrs) { // extensible to any number of arrays
  // construct an object with empty arrays for all available ids
  let rslt = _.chain(arrs)
              .flatten()
              .map(el => el.id)
              .uniq()
              .reduce((memo, el) => {
                memo[el] = []
                return memo
              }, {})
              .value()
  // as we iterate, first set resulting object's bucket value to null 
  // Replace this value if it exists while iterating
  _.each(arrs, (arr, i) => {
    _.each(rslt, v => {
      v.push(null)
    })
    _.each(arr, el => {
      rslt[el.id][i] = el
    })
  })
  return rslt
}

var arr1 = [{
  id: '3',
  text: 'arr1 - one'
}, {
  id: '2',
  text: 'arr1 - two'
}, {
  id: '1',
  text: 'arr1 - three'
}];

var arr2 = [{
  id: '4',
  text: 'arr2 - one'
}, {
  id: '2',
  text: 'arr2 - two'
}, {
  id: '1',
  text: 'arr2 - four'
}];

console.log(group(arr1, arr2))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.17.2/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

^ Run the snippet to see a log of the result.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `_.groupBy()` and `_.mapValues()`:

```js
const zipByKey = (arr1, arr2, zipKey) => {
  // group arr2 by the zipKey
  const group2 = _.groupBy(arr2, zipKey);
  
  return _(arr1)
    // group arr1 by the zipKey
    .groupBy(zipKey)
    // merge group1 with group2, if object is not in group1 substitute with null
    .mergeWith(group2, (objValue, srcValue) => (objValue || [null]).concat(srcValue))
    // map the groups, if object is not in group2 substitute with null
    .mapValues((group, zipKey) => group2[zipKey] ? group : group.concat(null))
    .value();
}

const arr1 = [{"id":"1","text":"arr1 - one"},{"id":"2","text":"arr1 - two"},{"id":"3","text":"arr1 - three"}], arr2 = [{"id":"1","text":"arr2 - one"},{"id":"2","text":"arr2 - two"},{"id":"4","text":"arr2 - four"}];

const result = zipByKey(arr1, arr2, 'id');

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.2/lodash.min.js"></script>
```